# Dynamic loading Backbone view with Requirejs

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I'm using require.js with Backbone in ordrer to load my differents views.

In order to define the view I'm using this piece of script that is launched by my Router:

```
var view = require([
  'hbs!tpl/'+name,
   'views/'+name,
   data.path       
], function(Tpl,module,data){

       options.template = Tpl;
       options.data = data;
       return new module(options);
});
```

The Backbone view receive the usefull options like the compiled template and the Model definition.

Is there a way to remove the script added by Require.js into the head tag when I remove my Backbone view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the script tag added by Require.js won't unload the javascript.

What I mean is that it is useless to remove this script tag. You just shouldn't care about this, it don't change anything to the way your page react.

Comment: Thanks Simon, but as long as it's a single page app, isn't it a risk to use a lot of memory ?

Comment: This is not using a lot of memory. Plus, loaded JavaScript don't use a lot of memory. What use memory is intensive process like huge Canvas and 3d rendering. And of course memory leaks in process happening often (like on scroll/resize listener, etc). In all case, Require.js won't consume a client memory and won't be the cause it crashes.

Comment: One more question, using this technique to load my differents views/models, will it be possible to optimize the full application using R.js ?

Comment: No, you can't use variables in define or require module name and expect it to be parsed by R.js. You should check [Backbone-Boilerplate](https://github.com/organizations/backbone-boilerplate) to help you get started on a good structure.

Comment: Well it's not completely impossible, you just have to get your hands dirty by writing a requirejs plugin.

Comment: @RaviHamsa Yes and no, if you use variable, the plugin won't know what resources to bundle, so even if it won't break R.js, the building won't be efficient.

Comment: @SimonBoudrias your are true, @adrien334 try using modules in require.js build configuration, only catch is whenever you add new dependency you need to add it as an include

`modules: [

        {
            name: 'apps/examples',
            include: [
                'apps/examples/app'
            ]
        }
    ]`